# In Eclipse WizardPage - Issues in Navigating between pages

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have written a small program which should navigate from one page to another. But I am unable to do that.

My requirement is

On PageOne, if the user Enters a value it should be validated i.e simple comparison in this case it is "123".
if it matches the proceed to the next page as shown below:

Page One

[image]

Page Two

[image]

else throw a dialogue box below:

Page One

[image]

Page One Code:

```java
    package testing.importWizards;

    import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
    import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.IWizardPage;
    import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage;
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

    public class PageOne extends WizardPage {
        private Text text1;
        private Composite container;
        boolean isVisible=false;

        public PageOne() {
            super("Page One");
            setTitle("Page One");
            setDescription("Fake Wizard: Page One");
        }

        @Override
        public void createControl(Composite parent) {
            container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
            GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
            container.setLayout(layout);
            layout.numColumns = 2;
            Label label1 = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
            label1.setText("Put a value here.");

            text1 = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
            text1.setText("");
            text1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (!text1.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        setPageComplete(true);
                    }
                }
            });
            GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
            text1.setLayoutData(gd);
            setControl(container);
            setPageComplete(false);
        }


        @Override
        public IWizardPage getNextPage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Shell shell=getShell();
            return super.getNextPage();
        }

        public String getText1() {
            return text1.getText();
        }
    }
```

Page Two Code:

```java
    package testing.importWizards;


    import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage;
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

    public class PageTwo extends WizardPage {
        private Text text1;
        private Composite container;

        public PageTwo() {
            super("Page Two");
            setTitle("Page Two");
            setDescription("Fake Wizard: Page Two");
        }

        @Override
        public void createControl(Composite parent) {
            container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
            GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
            container.setLayout(layout);
            layout.numColumns = 2;
            Label label1 = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
            label1.setText("Success");

            /*text1 = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
            text1.setText("");
            text1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    if (!text1.getText().isEmpty()) {
                        setPageComplete(true);
                    }
                }
            });*/
            GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
            //text1.setLayoutData(gd);
            setControl(container);
            //setPageComplete(false);
            setPageComplete(true);
        }

        public String getText1() {
            return text1.getText();
        }
    }
```

I have teid overriding setVisible and getNextPage Methods, but I am getting erroneous behaviour. Could someone please explaing me the logic for implementing the validation.  Is my entire approach wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than displaying a dialog it is usual for a wizard page to display errors in the top area of the wizard using `setErrorMessage` or `setError`.

Usually it is convenient to do the validation every time data on the page is changed. For your example page one something like:

```java
public class PageOne extends WizardPage
{
  private Text text1;

  public PageOne()
  {
    super("testWizardPage");

    setTitle("Page One");
    setDescription("Fake Wizard: Page One");
  }

  @Override
  public void createControl(final Composite parent)
  {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    Label label1 = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    label1.setText("Put a value here.");

    text1 = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
    text1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    text1.addModifyListener(this::modifyListener);

    setControl(container);

    setPageComplete(false);
  }    

  private void modifyListener(final ModifyEvent event)
  {
    boolean empty = text1.getText().isEmpty();

    if (empty)
      setErrorMessage("Text must be entered");
    else
      setErrorMessage(null);

    setPageComplete(!empty);
  }
}
```

This is using a 'modify listener' on the `text1` field and calling `setErrorMessage` and `setPageComplete` each time the field is changed.

Comment: Thanks  for your suggestion Greg, I have two points to discuss:1) Can we modify the logic such that the event is triggered only when Next Button is clicked 2) I have tried implementing this code. But the call is nor reaching to modifyListener(final ModifyEvent event).

Comment: This exact code works for me. `modifyListener` won't be called until you type something in the text field. As you already asked doing it only on next button is more complicated.

Comment: I have tried typing the listener is not getting called.  So, instead of wizard Page should I opt for something else?

Comment: I have never seen an issue with modify listener not working. You are using at least Java 8? `this::modifyListener` is a Java 8 method reference and won't work on earlier JVMs. You could also use the key listener code you were using and put the modifylistener code in the keyReleased.

Comment: Sorry Greg, My mistake. I cleaned the project and ran again it works like charm. Thanks a lot. :)